# How can i pass an Object from my Parent template to the Child Component

Tags: angular

i have a interface which looks like this

```
export interface IDropdownOption {
  guid: string;
  width: string;
  isRequired: false;
  fieldText: string;
  selectedItem: string;
}
```

In my Child component i define an Input like this
**@Input() compInfo: IDropdownOption;**
and then in my Parent template i use the client like this

```
<app-ig-dropdown
        compInfo.guid="820E04E0-8084-4D9C-A268-D8C0D21E74F6"
        compInfo.width="200px"
        formControlName="combo1"
        compInfo.fieldText="Social Media">
</app-ig-dropdown>
```

Doing so will always generate me errors that the property of any of these values defined in object compInfo are undefined. Is it even possible to use an Object as the @input and then set the values from the parent template ? 
I am trying to avoid declaring 50 + inputs as i might have 10 child components on the parent which each has 5 param.
If this is not supported how else can i make this more clean ?

Comment: You can pass an object as an `@Input`, but bear in mind that it *might not be set immediately*.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that ? How do i avoid the "AppComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'fieldText' of undefined
    at IgDropDownComponent.ngOnInit"

Comment: I mean the value might not be set when ngOnInit is called, or when the template is first rendered. You can deal with it using guard clauses, either in the component or the template, to ensure sensible default behaviour is provided.

Comment: Can you provide me with a simple sample o a guard clause and where to put it the the component. I assume it would check if the object is defined and if not wait till it is.

Comment: You can directly do like this: `<app-ig-dropdown [compInfo]="compInfoObj"> <app-ig-dropdown>`, no need to pass each property of the object. More over, the data which u needs to be received from parent `component`, you need to enclose it with`[]`.

Comment: but where do i pass the obj elements for the compInfoObj in the template like width="200px"

Comment: Component: `if (thing) { ... }`, template: `*ngIf="thing"`.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately i was able to solve the issue by assigning the values in my parent template like this.

```
<app-ig-dropdown
       [compInfo]="{guid :'820E04E0-8084-4D9C-A268-D8C0D21E74F6',
                    width:'350px',
                    placeHolder: ' -- Select --',
                    fieldText:'Social Media 1'}"
        formControlName="combo1"
        >
</app-ig-dropdown>
<app-ig-dropdown
        [compInfo]="{guid :'820E04E0-8084-4D9C-A268-D8C0D21E74F6',
                    width:'350px',
                    placeHolder: ' -- Select --',
                    fieldText:'Social Media 2'}"
        formControlName="combo2"
>
</app-ig-dropdown>
```